# Truncate text overflow but leaving space for button

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I'd like to truncate the text-overflow inside my td elements with dots and a button element. I'm having trouble leaving enough space at the end of the line to display a clipboard button. Below is my attempt with HTML/CSS:

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<button>&#128203;</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<button>&#128203;</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've also tried removing the button elements from my HTML so I could insert the ellipsis and button element through JavaScript. I'm not sure how to determine the cutoff length before I insert them. Below is my attempt with JavaScript:

```
(function addEllipsis(){
  const eles = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (let i = 0; i < eles.length; ++i){
    eles[i].innerHTML = eles[i].textContent.slice(0, -/*magic number*/) + '&#8230;<button>&#128203;</button>';
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap with some parent component inside the div like this .And add the parent component **[display:flex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)**.

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

td div p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
button{
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <button>&#128203;</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <button>&#128203;</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```